# Typescript can't find modules which are imported with webpack alias

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am currently setting up my project to be a bit cleaner, especially in the frontend part with references.

In hindsight I noticed that I was very generous with the folder structure for my frontend files and ended up with lots of layers. That's why I decided to look into what webpack can do for this case, and found out about the alias functionality.

This is how I set it up:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/Views/Components"),
        data: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/Data"),
        definitions: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/Definitions"),
        helper: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/Helper"),
        scripts: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts"),
        views: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/Views"),
    },
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
    modules: ["node_modules"]
}
```

As you can see, I created alias' for various folders here.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Now, let's hop into e.g. the LoginDialog.tsx. Here I am trying to import like this:

```
import { IErrorAttachedProperty } from "definitions/formHelper";
```

However, all I end up with here is an error that no module could be found this way.

What am I doing wrong here?

If it is of any significance - The webpack.config.js resides in the same directory as the Scripts folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to config tsconfig.json for typescript

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "components/*": [
    "./src(or any other path)/Scripts/Views/Components"
  ]
},
```

here is nice example [ts alias](https://medium.com/@caludio/how-to-use-module-path-aliases-in-visual-studio-typescript-and-javascript-e7851df8eeaa)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so to avoid confusion for others I'm posting my solution/findings:

<strike>Yes, you can just use `tsconfig.json` without needing `resolve/alias` in Webpack. You should just do it once with Typescript setup.</strike>

**EDIT:** Nope, turns out you do need `resolve/alias` section in `webpack.config.js`. Typescript will be happy without it, but then you will get Webpack errors when it builds. **Do both to make it work**.

**TIP:** Make sure the paths you provide in the `paths` section of `tsconfig.json` are relative to the `baseUrl` entry point. Don't make them relative to the `tsconfig.json` file, `baseUrl` is like the project root for the non-relative module imports defined with `paths`.

From Typescript docs, absolute modules names (import * from `package-a`) are relative to `baseUrl` ~ https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url

> All module imports with non-relative names are assumed to be relative to the baseUrl.

Relative modules (import * from `./packages`) are just from current file as stated:

> Note that relative module imports are not impacted by setting the baseUrl, as they are always resolved relative to their importing files.

So if you have:

```
./packages
  ./package-a
  ./package-b
./index.ts
./tsconfig.json
```

Your `tsconfig.json` would look like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./packages",
        "paths": {
            "package-a/*": [ "./package-a/*" ],
        },
    },
    "include": [
        "./packages/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Then your `webpack.config.json` would look like:

```
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'package-a': path.resolve(__dirname, 'packages/package-a/'),
        }
    },
}
```

Then you can import from `index.ts` like this:

```
import { pkgAThing } from 'package-a';
// or
import { otherPkgAThing } from 'package-a/dir/dir`;
```

Which is alternative to relative style:

```
import { pkgAThing } from './packages/package-a`;
```